# Authentification in just one file with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to use Sequelize, but I don't know how to figure out that : I want to connect only one time in the start.js, and not in each file.

This is my start.js :

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

// import environmental variables from our variables.env file
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });

// Connect to our Database
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    dialect: "postgres",
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    }
  }
);
// Try to authenticate to our databse
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(" Database connection successful !");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(" Database connection error...", err);
  });

// Start our app!
const app = require("./app");
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(` Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

And this is a random file (userController.js) when I want to execute a query :

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
// This is the problem:
const sequelize = new Sequelize; // (.connection() ?)

exports.getUsers = async (req, res) => {
  // Query the DB for a list of all users
  const users = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM profils");
  res.send({ users });
};
```

Thank you for your help ! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started) explains,

> Sequelize will setup a connection pool on initialization so you should ideally only ever create one instance per database if you're connecting to the DB from a single process.

So there should be a single instance, likely defined in a separate module:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports = new Sequelize(...);
```

that is imported in both middleware and main modules. As [the reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started#test-the-connection) also states, `authenticate` isn't really necessary but can be used to as a step for initialization routine:

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });

const sequelize = require('./db');

// for testability purposes
module.exports = sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    // Start our app!
    const app = require("./app");
    ...
    // for testability purposes
    return app;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```